# Bad Rendering - Subdivison surface

Tags: rendering, subdivision-surface

I have a truck model, It's been modeled with Blender 2.6x.

I've updated Blender (2.77). Before the update, my model is really ugly. So frustrating. When I enter edit mode, the model is smooth like a baby's soft skin.

The rendered version is really fragmented and It's really bad looking.

Do you have any idea, how can I solve this problem?

Thankx a lot!
[image]

Comment: Are the faces being distorted quads?

Comment: Yes they are. As you see the linked image the faces are all seems correct. I don't understand why, but the render result is a crap.

Comment: The image is taken in face select mode. It would not show additional vertices. You can verify by going into vert select mode, or using the "Select Faces By Sides" function (press space bar and search) and select all faces with sides not equal to 4.

Comment: Also try select all vert and remove doubles.

Comment: Maybe upload here - http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/ - you don't have to upload the whole model, but maybe a version with just the corner.